# convergence error in facebook prophet in python

Tags: python, forecasting, facebook-prophet

> INFO:fbprophet.forecaster:Disabling daily seasonality. Run prophet with daily_seasonality=True to override this.
>   Initial log joint probability = -2.46502
>   Iter log prob ||dx|| ||grad|| alpha alpha0 # evals Notes
>   99 402.571 0.000207143 101.815 0.9661 0.9661 136
>
> Iter log prob ||dx|| ||grad|| alpha alpha0 # evals Notes
>   199 402.966 1.93889e-06 74.3745 0.2165 0.7593 282
>
> Iter log prob ||dx|| ||grad|| alpha alpha0 # evals Notes
>   217 402.968 8.45346e-06 60.1757 1.2e-07 0.001 339 LS failed, Hessian reset
>   247 402.968 1.74976e-08 64.7367 0.2863 0.2863 382
>
> Optimization terminated normally:
>   Convergence detected: relative gradient magnitude is below tolerance

This output is coming for me. Please help.